# Using SpEL @Value to get payload or headers

Tags: spring-integration

I have a test class, and I would like to be able to use @Value to grab the headers or payload.

I made a number of SWAGS that have failed, and now I wonder if it is even possible.

Is there a way to write a SpEL that can get me the value of a header outside of the configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark answered to the same question on the Spring forum - @Value is evaluated once, when the context is loaded whereas the message payload and headers are runtime entities.

If you explain what you are trying to do, I am sure we can provide a solution.

Further to the discussion on the Spring Forum, [here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/5375131) that shows how to add a channel interceptor in your tests.